# How to totally block inbound mail on cPanel / WHM?

Tags: email, cpanel, whm

Is it possible to completely block inbound email on WHM / cPanel (without blocking sendmail / PHPMail from working)? If so, what config steps are required?

Comment: Yes, when creating an account select 0 as mail accounts, if you have already created accounts then simply modify those accounts and change the email limit to 0 and remove any existing email accounts.

Comment: This stops users from creating accounts, but I doesn't stop the WHM account from getting a default email account of its own. This default account is the catchall and can't be removed (from WHM: "The default account cannot be deleted and has no quota.")

Comment: Well you could edit the master ZONE file and remove the MX entries. This will prevent any emails being received period.

Comment: I thought there might be a service I can permanently disable?

Comment: Sadly I don't think its as easy as that because as far as I know there is no feature that allows you to disable that feature. Personally I would just edit the MX records or ignore it.

Comment: I feared that. iptables perhaps...

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Home »Service Configuration »Service Manager` and uncheck `Exim Mail Server`. This will disable Exim which is cPanel's SMTP server of choice.

This will however disable outgoing mail too. To workaround this, I suggest using a mail relay.

Another option is to go in to cPanel, and click `Default Address` - You can disable the catch-all and set all mail to send back a `:fail:` notification from here.